# How would I increment separate variables in a Class, instead of the object itself?

Tags: c++, class, object, variables, increment

Let's say there's a class Time which contains three data types Hour, Minute and Second. Using operator overloading, how would I increment these three variables separately?

Here's a counter example showing how incrementing using the ++ operator increments all the variables altogether. I want to increment them separately or only one. But I don't know how to access them through the object

```
    class Time
{
    private:
        int Hour, Minute, Second, option;
    public:
        Time() : Hour(13), Minute(59), Second(59)
        {
        }
        void operator ++ ()
        {
            ++Second;
            ++Minute;
            ++Hour;
        }
        void Display ()
        {
            cout << Hour << ":" << Minute << ":" << Second << endl;
        }
};

int main ()
{
    Time t;
    ++t;
    t.Display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Azzam, to give you an answer as accurate and helpful as possible, it would help to know, in broad terms, what you are trying to achieve with said class Time, and to see any code which you're written so far that might be relevant to your question.

Comment: I'm trying to use operator overloading to increment separate variables of an object created from the class Time. I would show the code but it's inconsequential as I've only made the class.

Comment: Show what you tried and describe your problem.

Comment: @Azzam Which operators do you need to overload? Could you give an example of the behavior you need? Could you give a counter-example showing what it would mean for the three variables to be incremented but not incremented "separately"?

Comment: I need to overload the ++ operator. I've now edited and given a counter example which increments Hour, Minute and Second all together.

Comment: Closed too soon. I've yet to receive any answers as to how I can access object variables to increment them and not the object itself. Needs to be reopened

Answer (score 0):

create a class with some public properties

```
class Time {
public:
    int hour = 0;
    int minute = 0;
    int second = 0;
};
```

and then create an instance of Time and update the properties

```
Time time = Time();

// assign whatever value you like
time.hour = 2;
time.minute = 32;
time.second = 324;

// or use the increment operator
time.hour++

// time.hour now contains the value 3
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I've to specifically use operator overloading to increment the variables.

Comment: Not the answer I'm looking for